# Handle DONE buttons and video finish playing events in UIWebview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebview which will play a YOUtube video playlist, and I need to handle the events when user click DONE button and close the webview.

So far, the working solution i found is to handle UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification, but when UIWebview finish playing a video in the list it will exit the fullscreen mode and enter back to fullscreen mode to play the next one. My app handles the event of exiting fullscreen as pressing DONE button and only the first song of the list get played.

My question is that is there anyway to handle DONE button click events without handling UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification, or to handle those two events separately?

Comment: I ask another question in more detail here.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150933/handle-control-buttons-of-uiwebview-youtube-video-player