# Handle control buttons of UIwebview youtube video player

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, youtube

I'm creating a youtube videos player which can play a list of youtube video ( given a list of video id). I embedded youtube video into a UIWebview as following:

```
NSString *htmlFormat = @"<html><head><body style=\"margin:0\"><embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" width=\"40\" height=\"30\"></embed></body></html>";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", videoId];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:htmlFormat, url];
[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
```

What i need are:

- Next video is played automatically when player finishes playing current one.
- Next video is played when user tap next button in players' control panel
- Stop playing list if user tap 'Done' button.

My approach is handling events that may be sent out when player finish playing, users tap control buttons, so i can modify html content to load other videos.

My question are:

1. **Is there better way to play a list of youtube video given a list of video ids?**
2. **How to handle such those events?**

I found [some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518719/how-to-receive-nsnotifications-from-uiwebview-embedded-youtube-video-playback/8554040#8554040) that suggest handle notification `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification` and `UIMoviePlayerControllerDidEnterFullscreenNotification`, but I can not distinguish between control buttons' events and finish playing event (movie player controller exits fullscreen mode in all the cases). Some suggest using HTML `<video>` tag, but i dont think it possible.